# MenuStrip items Enable/Disable vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to programaticaly Enable or Disable MenuStrip items.

Example if i have this

[image]

I want to disable the item2 and item3. Tried with

```
  MenuStrip1.Items("Item 1").Enabled = False
        MenuStrip1.Items(2).Enabled = False
```

Comment: Steve ok sorry for that. I edited the thread

Comment: Why the [new account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3772600/t3cho)?

Comment: @Plutonix that was my old account connected with facebook.

Comment: Describe the menu layout a little - are you trying to disable one of the top level items or one in the drop down list?  Also you can [merge accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256689/how-to-merge-user-profiles) so you dont lose priveleges (like ability to Up Vote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the image, it appears you want to disable/enable things in the dropdown.

Each top level menu item is itself an object which contains the actual drop down items - the MenuStrip is just a container for them. So, if I have a `File | View | Tools` menu, there will be three `ToolStripMenuItem`s to work with, each with a `DropDownItems` collection of those entries.  So:

```
ViewMenuItem.DropDownItems(2).Enabled = False
```

This disables the 3rd dropdown item on the View menu.  Yours might be named `ItemsToolStripMenuItem`.  The UI designer doesn't use a key to create/add new dropdown items, so the string overload wont work unless you are adding them manually:

```
' create new DD item
Dim foo = New ToolStripMenuItem("Foo", Nothing, 
              AddressOf FooToolStripMenuItem_Click, "Foo")
' add to menu
ViewMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(foo)

' access by key
ViewMenuItem.DropDownItems("Foo").Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this. I'm using VS Express 2013, and `ViewMenuItem.DropDownItems(2).Enabled = False` wouldn't work for me.

I found that this did.

```
ShowRawDataToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
```

My menu name in this instance is "Show raw data" or "ShowRawData"

I hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Item(1).Enabled = False
ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Item(2).Enabled = False
```